# How can I make a Regex that will match only alpha characters?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a sentence into words and then print them if they contain only alpha characters. Other characters should output an error message instead.

**Example Input:**

> The quick brown fox

**Desried Output:**

> The
>
> quick
>
> brown
>
> fox

**Example Input:**

> Th1 qu1ck br0wn fox

**Desired Output:**

> This is invalid.

I trried to do this using pattern but I think it didn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This will break a sentence into words.");
        Scanner alpha = new Scanner(System.in);
        String beta = alpha.nextLine();
        String [] data = beta.split(" ");
        if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", beta)){
            System.out.println(data[0]);
            System.out.println(data[1]);
            System.out.println(data[2]);
            System.out.println(data[3]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is not valid.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain more what you want your program to do? Also can you add the output of your program when you run it?

Comment: you split your sentence into words (btw use `"\\s+"` instead `" "`)  then all what you need to do is to use your expression against each word

Comment: You split the line, but then you check if the line itself is composed of letters only. This is going to be invalid, if you have spaces, or punctuation. Also, invalid if you have non-English characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy :).
You tried to match your pattern with the whole inputString "beta", but you splitted the "beta" already and you want to match the pattern not with beta, but with one element of your array "data".

Change this:

```
if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", beta)){}
```

to this:

```
for(String word : data)
{
  Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", word)
}
```

You have to handle the situation where the pattern not match, but thats your work. :)
I hope it helps.

Comment: the output prints "The quick brown fox" four times :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   System.out.println("This will break a sentence into words.");
        Scanner alpha = new Scanner(System.in);
        String beta = alpha.nextLine();
        String [] data = beta.split("\\s+");
        boolean valid = true;
        for (String word: data)
        if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", word)){
               valid = false
                break;
         }
         if(valid)
        System.out.println("This is valid.");
            else
        System.out.println("This is not valid.");
```

small tweaks if your word contains more tnat standards 26 letters

```
String beta = "Dieser Satz ist ungültig. This is valid";
String[] data = beta.split("[\\s+|\\.+]+");
boolean valid = true;

a: for (String word : data)
    for (char c : word.toCharArray())
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
            valid = false;
            break a;
        }

 if(valid)
       for (String word : data)
           System.out.println(word);
   else
        System.out.println("This is not valid.");
```

Comment: `This sentence is invalid.` `Also, this one` because of punctuation and `Dieser Satz ist ungültig` (note: used Google translate for the last one).

Comment: output should be: the quick brown fox but the words should be above(dont know the term) each other

Answer (score 0):

One more option with checking the whole line before parsing the words:

```
 private static boolean isValidSymbols(String s) {
    return  s != null && s.matches("[a-zA-Z\\s]+");
 }

 private static void checkInput(String s) {
     if (isValidSymbols(s)) {
         for (String word : s.split("\\s+")) {
             System.out.println(word);
         }
     } else {
         System.out.println("This is not valid.");
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     checkInput("The quick brown fox");
     checkInput("Th1 quick br0wn fox");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand a question, the simple way is to check the letters with ASCII code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This will break a sentence into words.");
        Scanner alpha = new Scanner(System.in);
        String beta = alpha.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<beta.length(); i++) {
            if (((int)beta.charAt(i) > 64 && (int)beta.charAt(i) < 91) || ((int)beta.charAt(i) > 96 && (int)beta.charAt(i) < 123) || ((int)beta.charAt(i) == 32)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == beta.length()) {
            System.out.println("correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about non-English characters?

Comment: @Vld, I think that he uses just English characters, because in his regular expression he uses: `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: It depends if it was intended or not. Notice that OP is a novice (no disrespect intended), thus he may just not be aware of the impact.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
    String str = "This is a brown fox";
    String patternStr= "[0-9]{1}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.find()){
      System.out.println("invalid");
    }else{
        System.out.println("valid");
    }
```

Thanks,
JK

Comment: So, `The qu!ck brown fox` is valid?

Comment: Why the `{1}`? Since this is regex, why not just use the pattern "`\d`"?